# Termux storage permission

Tags: javascript, sass, storage, termux

I have been trying to access my internal storage using this directory:

`/storage/Code/workspace/Try/css/index.scss`

But termux tells me `bash`:

`/storage/Code/workspace/Try/css/index.scss: No such file or directory.`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: So did you check to confirm if that file or directory exists like it is asking? You are trying to access is a `SCSS` file, not a directory, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue this command `termux-setup-storage`

For more details here's [a link](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-setup-storage) I hope it works for you

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Edit your answer and add an explination and links to official docs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was, you didn't write directory name properly. If you don't know about your internal storage name or internal storage's root directory name (ex: `/storage/emulator/0` which can be different on others devices) you can find that with this simple `df` command, and as we know that, android's internal or external storage is situated in `/storage`, so we can only grab or **filter that folder name info** only by saying **`df | grep storage`**

```
✓ u0_axxx@localhost ~ $ df | grep storage
/dev/fuse                                        xxxxxxx xxxxxx  xxxxx  xx% /storage/emulated
```

Here `/storage/emulated` is the internal storage's entry point and somtimes the directory name for some devices is '/storage/emulated/0'. So your directory should be somthing like, `/storage/emulated/0/Code/workspace/Try/css/index.scss` or maybe different for you.

You can watch more infos about your directories by writting the `df` command without any filter:

```
✓ u0_axxx@localhost ~ $ df
Filesystem                                      1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/dm-0                                   xxxxxx xxxxxx    xxxxxx  89% /
tmpfs                                              xxxxxx    xxxx    xxxxxx   1% /dev
tmpfs                                              xxxxx      xx    xxxxx   1% /mnt
/dev/block/dm-2                                  xxxxxx xxxxxx  xxxxxxx  11% /mnt/expand/7843497a-bd2b-40df-82ee-1eb72580c0f7
/dev/block/dm-1                                    xxxxxx  xxxxxx    xxxxxx  43% /vendor
tmpfs                                              xxxxx       0    xxxxxx   0% /apex
/dev/block/platform/bootdevice/by-name/userdata   xxxxxx xxxxx   xxxxx  82% /data
/dev/fuse                                        xxxxxx xxxxxx  xxxxx  xx% /storage/emulated
```

Thanks.